# Using separate .php file for functions - how to run on site?

Tags: functions

Instead of bogging down my child theme's `functions.php` file, I would like to have a separate .php file that has various functions, that I can call within `functions.php` (and in other files).

I have created `my-custom-functions.php` within my child theme, where the `functions.php` lives.

Here's the folder structure:

```
wp-content
    themes
        grow-minimal-child
            functions.php
            my-custom-functions.php
```

Code for `my-custom-functions.php`:

```
<?php

function js_log($msg){
  return "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
}

echo js_log("Hello!");
```

And the first few lines of `functions.php`:

```
<?php
include_once(get_theme_roots() . '/grow-minimal-child/rs-custom-functions.php');
```

But, when I load any page, I get this error:

> Warning: include_once(/themes/grow-minimal-child/my-custom-functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/grow-minimal-child/functions.php on line 2

What do I need to fix, it looks like the `include_once` is looking for `functions.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_theme_roots()` and `get_theme_root()` aren't really appropriate functions for getting the path to a file from a theme.

I recommend you use [`get_theme_file_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_path/) instead:

```
include_once get_theme_file_path( 'grow-minimal-child/rs-custom-functions.php' );
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking there was a better function.  I'll check the documentation as to why; I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error was using `get_theme_roots()`.  This returns a relative path.

`get_theme_root()` returns `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes`
`get_theme_roots()` returns `/themes`

By switching that to `get_theme_root()` (note singular), it was able to correctly locate the custom `.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [get_stylesheet_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) as you're using a child theme.

Something like, 
`include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/rs-custom-functions.php');`

Comment: Looks like that returns the same path as `get_theme_roots()` (at least in this instance). Thanks!